# VB Depreciation

Tags: vb.net

So here is where I am at.  I can't get anything to display on the list box that I created named "depreciationListBox" I have been working on this project for a while and I am quite stumped.  Any pointers or solutions that anyone could help me would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub displayButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles displayButton.Click

  Dim cost As Double
  Dim life As Double = CDbl(lifeListBox.SelectedItem)
  Dim period As Double
  Dim nextPeriod As Double
  Dim salvage As Double
  Dim depreciation As Double
  Dim isConvertedCost As Boolean
  Dim isConvertedLife As Boolean
  Dim isConvertedSalvage As Boolean

  isConvertedCost = Double.TryParse(AssetTextBox.Text, cost)
  isConvertedLife = Double.TryParse(lifeListBox.Text, life)
  isConvertedSalvage = Double.TryParse(salvageTextBox.Text, salvage)

  For nextPeriod = 1 To period Step 1
    depreciation = Financial.DDB(cost, salvage, life, nextPeriod)
    depreciationListBox.Text += nextPeriod.ToString & "    " & _
      Convert.ToString(depreciation) _
      & ControlChars.NewLine
  Next nextPeriod

  If isConvertedCost AndAlso isConvertedLife _
      AndAlso isConvertedSalvage Then
    depreciationListBox.Text = "    Year    Depreciation   "
  End If
End Sub
```

Where did I go wrong?  Here is a link to what the assignment is and an image of how it is supposed to look: http://books.google.com/books?id=UAo8tAQRvGUC&pg=PT415&lpg=PT415&dq=sonheim+manufacturing&source=bl&ots=G74EzxAphD&sig=tS7s6EUUmgWrq6ZXphhDhDaBpsw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KM8pT7mPA6qq2QWtq_ncAg&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=sonheim%20manufacturing&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you loop from 1 to period, but you never initialize period. The default value for period would be 0, which means the loop will never run.

Answer (score 2):

Use `depreciationListBox.Items.Add(nextPeriod.ToString & "    " &           Convert.ToString(depreciation))`

For VB6, you should use .AddItem.

Comment: Hmmm well I used your code in place of mine and still nothing prints out in the list box....nothing displays anywhere.

Comment: I think Dmitry is correct. Check out the example given at the MSDN doco for this; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx You can see in this example how they set up a multi column list box (rather than relying on spaces) and how they then add items to it (as Dmitry has done above).